# Сохранить значение вектора пока оно не изменилось

Tags: python, numpy

Есть вектор со значениями `1.0`, `-1.0` или `nan`.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, -1.0, np.nan, -1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan])
```

Задача сохранить предыдущее значение вектора до другого значения опуская `nan`. Без циклов.

В результате должно быть:

`[nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, -1.0, np.nan, -1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan])
arr = pd.Series(arr).fillna(method="ffill").to_numpy()
print(arr) # [nan  1.  1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, -1.0, np.nan, -1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan])

class Replacer:
    current = np.nan

    def __call__(self, v):
        if not np.isnan(v):
            self.current = v 
        return self.current

new_arr = np.fromiter(map(Replacer(), arr), dtype=arr.dtype)
print(new_arr)  # -> [nan 1.0 1.0 1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
```